# Deleting an item from my redux state gives multiple errors

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, jsx

I am having 2 issues:

1. Initially I can add clients to the empty array through action creators and my reducer. However, whenever I delete the items from the list and try to add new clients to it, it gives me an error: TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
2. When I said I am deleting the items, what really happens is I create the clients, and then when I click on the delete button next to one of them, all of the clients delete. There is not error in the console, but I just want to delete the specific client with the corresponding id.

Here is my code!

Clients.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import AddClient from './AddClient'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {deleteClient} from '../../store/actions/clientActions'

class Clients extends Component {

  handleClick = (id) => {
    console.log(id)
    this.props.deleteClient(id)
  }

  render() {
    const {clientList} = this.props
    return (
      <div className="container mt-5">
        <h2>Here Are Your List of Clients...</h2>
        {clientList && clientList.map(client => {
          return(
            <div key={client.id}>
              <div>
                Client Name: {client.name} | Client Price: {client.price}
                <button onClick={() => {this.handleClick(client.id)}}>Delete</button>
              </div>      
            </div>
          )
        })}
        <AddClient/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    clientList : state.clients.clientList,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return{
    deleteClient : (id) => dispatch(deleteClient(id)) 
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Clients)
```

Actions:

```
export const addClient = (client) => {
    return(dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch({type: 'ADD CLIENT', client})
    }
}

export const deleteClient = (id) => {
    return(dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch({type: 'DELETE CLIENT', id})
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
const initState = {
    clientList: []
}

const clientReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD CLIENT' : 
            action.client.id = Math.random();
            let clientList =  [...state.clientList, action.client];
            clientList.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
            return {
                clientList
            };

        case 'DELETE CLIENT' :
            const id = action.id;
            clientList = state.clientList.filter(client => 
                {return client.id !== id});
            return clientList;

        default : return state;
    }
}

export default clientReducer
```

Lastly, this is AddClient.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {addClient} from '../../store/actions/clientActions'

class AddClient extends Component {
  state = {
    id: null,
    name: null,
    price: null,
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({
          [e.target.id] : e.target.value
      })
  } 

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.addClient(this.state);
    e.target.reset();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="mt-5">
            <h3>Add a new client:</h3>
            <label htmlFor="name">Client Name: </label>
            <input type="text" id="name" onChange={this.handleChange}/><br/>
            <label htmlFor="price">Client Price: </label>
            <input type="text" id="price" onChange={this.handleChange}/> <br/>
            <button className="btn btn-primary">Add Client</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addClient: (client) => dispatch(addClient(client))
  }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AddClient)
```

Thank you for all the help, I am fairly new to React and Redux. Let me know if there is any other code you would like to see.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can accomplish the delete:

```
export const deleteClient = (id) => {
    const index = find the index of the client you want to delete from the array
    return(dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch({type: 'DELETE CLIENT', index})
    }
}



case 'DELETE CLIENT' :
    return {
        ...state,
        clientList: [
              ...state.clientList.slice(0, action.index),
              ...state.clientList.slice(action.index + 1)
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the problem is within my clientReducer.js

This needs to change:

```
case 'DELETE CLIENT' :
    const id = action.id;
    clientList = state.clientList.filter(client => 
       {return client.id !== id});
    return clientList;
```

to...

```
case 'DELETE CLIENT' :
    const id = action.id;
    let newClientList = state.clientList.filter(client => {
        return id !== client.id;
    })
    return {clientList : newClientList};
```

Comment: This change fixed both issues I was having! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
case 'DELETE CLIENT' :
        const id = action.id;
        const clientList = state.clientList.filter(client => 
            {return client.id !== id});
        return {
            ...state,
            clientList
        }
```

You're currently returning just an array, instead of an object.  Since that's probably the only thing you have in your redux store right now, it's not breaking (in the ADD action), but you probably want to apply the previous state first, then add your newly filtered clientlist to the state you're returning.